# Translation of 無理に取ろうとしないで

Tags: expressions

Can someone tell me what the expression 無理に取ろうとしないで means? I tried searching for the different parts in dictionary and the internet, but did not succeed.
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

無理 = force
無理に = forcibly
取る = to take
取ろうとしない(で) = to try not to take (please)

無理に取ろうとしないで
Please don't try to take by force (forcibly).

~ようとする
This is a grammar point meaning to attempt to do something, so if you change する into しない, it means to try not to do something.

I hope this helps!